# Query to fetch sequences of distinct records with LIMIT and OFFSET

Tags: mysql, sql, database

So, my question may be confusing and you may ask what do I mean exactly?
Let's assume I've the following table (contacts) in my database:

```
+----+----------+-----------+
| id | provider |   name    |
+----+----------+-----------+
|  1 | MSC      | Roger     |
|  2 | DLL      | Steven    |
|  3 | DLL      | Pensi     |
|  4 | DLL      | Kendswill |
|  5 | MSC      | Mark      |
|  6 | LAPTON   | Steffan   |
|  7 | MSC      | John      |
|  8 | MSC      | Cori      |
|  9 | LAPTON   | Jason     |
+----+----------+-----------+
```

I'm looking to fetch for example 3 records, so it must be in a specific sequence - the query should yield a sequence (or sequences) of one record for each provider, distinct ones in each sequence **(based on the provider in this example)**, for example, if the LIMIT set to 4, I should get:

```
+----+----------+-----------+
| id | provider |   name    |
+----+----------+-----------+
|  1 | MSC      | Roger     |
|  4 | DLL      | Kendswill |
|  6 | LAPTON   | Steffan   |
|  7 | MSC      | John      |
+----+----------+-----------+
```

And if I would set the LIMIT to 4 and set an OFFSET of 4, now I should get:

```
+----+----------+--------+
| id | provider |  name  |
+----+----------+--------+
|  5 | MSC      | Mark   |
|  2 | DLL      | Steven |
|  9 | LAPTON   | Jason  |
|  8 | MSC      | Cori   |
+----+----------+--------+
```

And so on and so forth.
As you may see, it should be consistent and should be organized always in the same way (not a random way).

I've heard about gap and islands, but wonder if someone could shed some light on the subject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign each row that has the same provider with an increasing number.  Then you can sort by that number. The rows that have an 1 for each provider will show up first, followed by those with the number two.

```
select  *
from    (
        select  @rn := case when provider = @lastprovider then @rn + 1 else 1 end
        ,       @lastprovider := provider
        ,       @rn as provider_row_num
        ,       provider
        ,       name
        from    Table1
        ,       (select @rn := 0, @lastprovider := '') init        
        order by
                provider
        ,       id
        ) sub
order by
        provider_row_num
,       provider
limit   4
```

[Working example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9ebc2c/14/0)

Comment: There's a good article on [gaps and islands here](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/the-sql-of-gaps-and-islands-in-sequences/) but I don't think it fits your question

Comment: Well the process looks the same (at least from the examples I saw), but anyway, it works like a charm. Is that a good practice in tables with 1000 records?

Comment: This solution will work and has good performance. But relying on the sort order goes against the SQL standard. So whether this is good practice depends on who is asking :)

Comment: Well, honestly it is a troublemaker customer, and the solution is a such the one you've provided or to do the work on the server application - I would prefer to stick with the SQL approach =) 

Thanks for the great solution!